# Google Script: how to send Tablechart in e-mail?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm creating a tablechart in Google Script and I want to send this through e-mail.

This is my code

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Month')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Online')
      .addRow(['January', 10, 1])
      .addRow(['February', 12, 1])
      .addRow(['March', 20, 2])
      .addRow(['April', 25, 3])
      .addRow(['May', 30, 4])
      .build();

  var chart = Charts.newTableChart()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .enableSorting(true)
      .build();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "me@gmail.com",
    subject: "Test",
    htmlBody: "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:inImage'> images! <br>",
    inlineImages:
      {
        inImage: chart.getBlob().setContentType('image/png'),
      }
  });
```

The code gives the following error message on `chart.getBlob().setContentType('image/png')`:

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again".

Anyone any idea what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
var chart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataTable(data)
    .enableSorting(true)
    .build();
```

#### To:

```
var chart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataTable(data)
    .enableSorting(true)
    .setDimensions(640, 480) // Added
    .build();
```

It sets the size of chart using `setDimensions()`.

#### Note:

- Also you can use `chart.getAs('image/png')` instead of `chart.getBlob().setContentType('image/png')`.

#### Reference:

- [setDimensions(width, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/table-chart-builder#setdimensionswidth-height)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: HI Tanaike,

Setting the dimensions did the job, great!!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike , this one also helped me with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241636/google-apps-script-insert-data-table-into-google-slide/71243184#71243184
You can go by and leave your answer there as well if you like